# What is "New Creation" according to Catholicism?

Tags: catholicism

> [2 Corinthians 5:17 (ESV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Corinthians%205:17&version=ESV)
>
> Therefore, if anyone is in Christ, he is a **new creation**. The old
>   has passed away; behold, the new has come.

I don't know if this subject has importance in Catholicism. Therefore, I want to know what Catholicism has to offer regarding this topic.

How has Catholicism explained what is *"New Creation"*?

Comment: Wooh. The Catechism has an [enormous amount](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="new+creation"+site:vatican.va) to say about it!

Comment: I found a resource that might be able to answer the asker's question. The problem is, you have to borrow the book from the library. Here it is. **Hubbard, M. V. (2002). New creation in Paul's letters and thought. Cambridge, UK: Cambridge University Press.** It's written by a professor from Biola University, but I am not sure if he's Catholic.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as a Catholic, I'm not going to attempt to interpret the Bible, here's the commentary from the New American Bible:

> A new creation: rabbis used this expression to describe the effect of the entrance of a proselyte or convert into Judaism or of the remission of sins on the Day of Atonement. The new order created in Christ is the new covenant.

I asked a [similar question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4866/whats-the-new-rite-in-tantum-ergo) concerning St. Thomas Aquinas' Hymn  concerning the what he meant by the **New Rite** and apparently he's talking about the New Covenant and the New Covenant is the Gospel message which is Salvation through Christ.

---

At a superficial level, I'd assume he was talking about Baptism.  When you're baptized you're made a "new creation" in Jesus.  The new creation would be the new life of the spirit dwelling within the newly minted Christian.

Answer (score 0):

**Children of God**
*sons in the Son*

cf. [What is unique about Christianity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/what-is-unique-about-christianity/30905#30905)

---

> What shall be said of ... **that new creation of the soul, whereby he
>   makes us his children** ... **gives us a new and heavenly nature**,
>   implants his Holy Spirit within us, and washes away all our sins? This
>   is the portion of the Christian, high or low; **and all glories of
>   this world fade away before it**; king and subject ... are all on a
>   level in the kingdom of Christ.
>    - *Unless a man is born again of water and Holy Spirit, he cannot enter the Kingdom.* P.S.*VIII, 52-53*
>
> **Source:** *12. The Mass and Sacraments | The Mind of cardinal Newman, Compiled by Charles Stephen Dessain | Catholic Truth Society*